# Soundcard Xonar DGX only works 'sometimes'

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, arch-linux, sound-card

Since about half a year, i am having a really confusing time with my Soundcard. When I boot my PC up it feels like there is a gamble going on that is deciding if the Sound Card works now. If it does not work, I always restart my PC a few times and after a non deterministic amount of times, the Sound Card gets recognized and will be automatically used.

- OS: Arch Linux x86_64
- Kernel: 5.0.4-arch1-1-ARCH
- Desktop-Environment: Xfce
- Audio: Pulseaudio/Alsa

I used the "lspci -v" command when it was working:

> Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
>
> Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. CMI8786 (Xonar DGX)
>
> Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 44, NUMA node 0
>
> I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
>
> Capabilities: access denied
>
> Kernel driver in use: snd_oxygen
>
> Kernel modules: snd_oxygen

and when it was NOT working:

> Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
>
> Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. CMI8786 (Xonar DGX)
>
> Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 15, NUMA node 0
>
> I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=256]
>
> Capabilities: access denied
>
> Kernel modules: snd_oxygen

To be honest I am not really great in the 'Linux Audio Stuff', so I hope you can help with this.